# Expression Engine - Multiple URL's for Template Group

Tags: php, expressionengine

Is it possible in EE2 to have 2 URL's to map to a template group?

E.g: I have a template called "multi_template" - Could I map multiple segment 1's to this like (/url1 , /url2...).

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Page module to do that. See the doc for details: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/pages/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I build all my EE sites with Structure (www.buildwithstructure.com), and it allows you to map any URL to any template group and template.

I think there is similar capability in Pages, but I've never used it.

Another option, though it may drag performance, would be to make  templategroup2/template2 contain an embed that loads templategroup1/template1. With cacheing, it may not impact performance.